# how to transform label text to UTF-8 in c#

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm Trying to transform label's text to utf-8 in c# what should I have to do ?

```
            lblName.Text = e.displayName;
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more context... Normally when you start converting strings manually like that, you are asking for all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the solution that is mention in the MSDN Example over there:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.90).aspx

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class UTF8EncodingExample {
public static void Main() {
    // Create a UTF-8 encoding.
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

    // A Unicode string with two characters outside an 8-bit code range.
    String unicodeString =
        "This unicode string contains two characters " +
        "with codes outside an 8-bit code range, " +
        "Pi (\u03a0) and Sigma (\u03a3).";
    Console.WriteLine("Original string:");
    Console.WriteLine(unicodeString);

    // Encode the string.
    Byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(unicodeString);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Encoded bytes:");
    foreach (Byte b in encodedBytes) {
        Console.Write("[{0}]", b);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // Decode bytes back to string. 
    // Notice Pi and Sigma characters are still present.
    String decodedString = utf8.GetString(encodedBytes);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Decoded bytes:");
    Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the encoding of a string. In .NET, strings are internally encoded using UTF-16. You can only influence the encoding when a string is converted to/from a byte sequence (e.g. written to / read from a file).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, String uses UTF-16. Hence you might not have problem with this.

I think you are having problem with your html character set.

To make page charset as "UTF-8", set the following on the page header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: actually I'm getting data with Turkish Characters so I need to show this data to UTF-8.